# 3x3 grid should not be so difficult

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Not looking as expected:

```css
.cont {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 33% 33% 33%;
    grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
}
.cont > div {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div>cell 1</div><div>cell 2</div><div>cell 3</div>
  <div>cell 4</div><div>cell 5</div><div>cell 6</div>
  <div>cell 7</div><div>cell 8</div><div>cell 9</div>
</div>
```

so obviously the expected outcome would be a tic-tac-toe like grid of equal squares. However the height flattens to the content of each div, i have 9 of them. I tried everything setting height to 100% in container div and individual divs, it always flattens regardless of content. Problem is different squares will be empty or have content at different times. If I set a specific height on the rows, ex. 250px it works fine, but it will not work with percentages for some reason. I just want 9 equal squares regardless of browser height and width in px. You would think this would not be so difficult.

Comment: try `grid-auto-rows: 1fr`

Comment: and why is it always height that is the issue, It does 3 columns perfectly. but rows, always an issue.

Comment: It is not difficult. You just don't seem to understand how `%` works in CSS. Learn about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)

Answer (score 3):

To fill the screen (and not exceed it) the maximum size of the columns/rows is 1/3 of the viewport **height**.

So we set the columns widths to `33.33vh` (1/3 of viewport height) and use `aspect-ratio` on the children to ensure they stay square.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33.3vh);
}

.square {
  aspect-ratio: 1 /1;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. PS: `aspect-ratio: 1;` will do the same as `1 /1`. Also, it's subjectively better to avoid `padding: 0;` in the quick reset CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like below:

```css
.cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* 3 columns */
  width: 100vmin; /* 100% of the smallest between height and width of screen */
  aspect-ratio: 1; /* square */
  gap: 5px; /* you can also have gap*/
}

.cont > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  /* center everything */
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div>cell 1</div>
  <div>cell 2</div>
  <div>cell 3</div>
  <div>cell 4</div>
  <div>cell 5</div>
  <div>cell 6</div>
  <div>cell 7</div>
  <div>cell 8</div>
  <div>cell 9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want the container to fill the height, I would use `height: 100vh` so that the div will be the height of the viewport.

I added children inside the container for demonstration purposes. The grid children will automatically fill their grid cell.

Also, if you would like the columns and rows to be evenly distributed, you can use `repeat()`, which will set the amount of columns/rows and the size of each as well.

You can read more about `repeat()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).

Read more about the `vh` unit of measurement [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units).

```css
html, body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.cont {
  background-color: #171717;
  height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0.25rem;
}

.testing-box {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="testing-box"></div>
  <div class="testing-box"></div>
  <div class="testing-box"></div>
  <div class="testing-box"></div>
  <div class="testing-box"></div>
  <div class="testing-box"></div>
  <div class="testing-box"></div>
  <div class="testing-box"></div>
  <div class="testing-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: your on the right track, what does the VH property do and why is it required for height but not width. Also creates an annoying scrollbar, wish there was a way to get rid of that.

Comment: Block elements automatically fill the width of their container so `.cont` fills the whole screen. `vh` stands for veiw height. Since we set the height to `100vh`, it tells the div to be 100 of the view. I added a link to the answer for more details on the `vh` property. The scroll bar showed up because of default browser padding and margin settings on `html` and `body`. I added a small css reset to remove padding and margin and now the scrollbar isn't showing. @user3005635

Comment: This doesn't create squares